# Adding two buttons next to an ExtJS ComboBox

Tags: button, combobox, extjs, grouping, fieldset

I need to place an Add button and a Remove button next to an ExtJS ComboBox. It's critical for these three elements to be in a single line because I have to apply this to all other ComboBoxes in the fieldset too.

Please notice that the given ComboBoxes are items of a fieldset. Replacing the buttons with context menu items is not the desired solution.

Can you give me some ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can place all the three elements - combobox and the two buttons - in a container with layout hbox. This will place all of them in the same line.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ext.form.FieldContainer is the class you need.

It has a label and will layout nicely with your form, but can contain multiple fields and controls.